# Create new type from generic type

Tags: typescript, type-conversion, typescript-generics

I am trying to create a new object type based on a generic type, but my typescript keeps saying it is the incorrect type.
For example: I want to convert all the objects properties to string.

-- Edited the example to be more complete
Entry type

```js
interface Example {
  value1: string;
  value2: number;
  value3: {
     value4: boolean
  }
}

// Expected new type
interface NewExample {
  value1: string;
  value2: string;
  value3: {
   value4: string
 }
}
```

My current function basicly converts all the objects properties to string: (assume there isnt arrays)

```js
public convertObject<T>(obj: T) {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach( prop => {
        const value = obj[prop];
        if(typeof value === 'object') 
            obj[prop] = this.convertObject(obj[prop])
        else 
            obj[prop] = 'example'+obj[prop]
    })
    return obj;
}
```

Given I apply the function on a defined object, all I want is that every "typeof" of any property be a string.

How can I achieve that?

Edit:

```js
  let a = { _number: 1, _obj: {mock: true} };
    let b = this.convertObject(a);
    b._obj; // This should me an object
    b._obj.mock; // This should me a string
```

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/xvgujq Stackblitz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can express this type transformation as follows:

```
type ConvertObject<T> = 
   T extends object ? { [K in keyof T]: ConvertObject<T[K]> } : string;
```

That's a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) which checks if its input type `T` is an object, and if so, evaluates to [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) where each property is recursively transformed; and if not, evaluates to just `string`.  You can verify that it does the right thing to `Example`:

```
type NewExample = ConvertObject<Example>;
/* type NewExample = {
    value1: string;
    value2: string;
    value3: {
        value4: string;
    };
} */
```

---

For the actual implementation of `convertObject()`, it's hard/impossible to convince the compiler that what you're doing is type safe (see [microsoft/TypeScript#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912) for the current state of affairs with implementing functions whose call signatures are generic conditional types), so you will probably need to use [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) or the equivalent to loosen the type checking inside the implementation enough to avoid compiler errors.

Here's one way to do it:

```
function convertObject<T extends object>(obj: T): ConvertObject<T> {
  const ret: any = {};
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(prop => {
    const value = (obj as any)[prop];
    ret[prop] = typeof value === 'object' ? convertObject(value) : ('example ' + value);
  })
  return ret;
}
```

Note that I've made this a standalone function (and not a class method), and that it does not mutate the passed-in `obj` in place, but returns a new object `ret`.  TypeScript's type system really cannot model the situation where something of type (say) `number` changes to a `string`.  So if you call `convertObject(obj)`, the type of `obj` seen by the compiler will not be changed, and you run the risk of runtime errors if you actually do change the type of `obj`.  So I'd recommend avoiding such mutation; if you really *need* to change the passed in `obj`, you should be very careful not to use `obj` again afterward.

And also note the type loosening inside the implementation; I treat `obj` as `any` and make `ret` of type `any` so that the compiler doesn't complain.  This places the burden of maintaining type safety on me (or you), so we should check and double check that `convertObject()` actually does produce an output of type `ConvertObject<T>` when its input is of type `T`.

---

Let's test to see if it works:

```
let a = { _number: 1, _obj: { mock: true } };
let b = convertObject(a);
/* let b: {
    _number: string;
    _obj: {
        mock: string;
    };
} */
console.log(b._number.toUpperCase()); // EXAMPLE 1
console.log(b._obj.mock.toUpperCase()); // EXAMPLE TRUE
```

Looks good.  The type of `b` is seen by the compiler to be exactly what you want, and the implementation works also.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=26&ssc=35&pln=26&pc=36#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKIA84FsAOAbFAbwChlkA3OPAVwgEYAuZAZzClAHMBuUiq2gExMQ1LACNoPMpRoQAzExJlp-CABYmYgPZaCcELwC+xY8WJgAnjhQBhLSHLQwAeTEArCAjAAeACoA+ZABeZF9kCHRIEAATZmQtd08wZAB+ZEJkAG0AaWRQZABrCAstGFCAXSY7BydXDy8-HPLAw2QmVnYQbjNLa2QAOQgAdwxsfBQQ6scoF0SG0dwCfx4AegAqZF6UQZHMRYn03hVZRhY2TillGUF2867L49oFQ+VXvlkNM87u18MeVrWKzMMGoIC8wHsyAQ9mms3qPjCESisXiczA-gAFAk3ExfABKKow2povzLYggsFgCEgKFEmZ1JJY9xMfQWPEvWkgVjIKAQZIhQitOBxVmXBleAB0RQszCZbjxEpgWigqEQAAsMTgoFocMFAkplNCuclrgdsZktTryg8eXyLdqcOVgpsrBBSu9aMEgiEAOTYpI+1Kc2HisAY03spgYn0RMYEZCBgDUHogeMuhjxvF5YGoUBp2f+ZgIyTgzoyAH0ROJoEw6AAaZDl7GKZBYLQIApMNie1p-YjF5BiZ1GkNojFwNPEdbIAdiRRHRtViRQW7fG1N5kct6t9udr4XBd9gFAo3MXQQCV4LQcDFiCWV0TLiVgLQAVRw1igNmFEAxeLTyArCsaAABoAIIALIAAoADKoMgdDEKe56Xtet73tiEpth2z5vh+0Dfswv7-lwgHAag4HQXBoQAEqvqgxBAA)

Answer (score 1):

```js
type ValueOf<O> = O[keyof O];

function convertObject<O extends Record<string, any>, V extends ValueOf<O>>(
  obj: O
): V extends Record<any, any>
  ? Record<keyof O, Record<keyof V, string>>
  : Record<keyof O, string> {
  (Object.keys(obj) as Array<keyof O>).forEach((prop) => {
    const value = obj[prop];
    if (typeof value === 'object') {
      obj[prop] = convertObject(obj[prop]) as ValueOf<O>;
    } else {
      obj[prop] = ('example' + obj[prop]) as ValueOf<O>;
    }
  });
  return obj;
}

const hello: Example = {
  value1: 'fdsafd',
  value2: 444,
  value3: {
    value4: true
  },
  another: {
    thing: 3213
  }
};

const thing = convertObject(hello);
```

`thing` should correctly be typed there with each value as a string. The only thing was you have to add `as` statements, otherwise the TS compiler will complain that the types are incompatible.

Comment: It worked parcialy, it doens't work with nested object, it is returning them as string;   let a = { _number: 1, _obj: {mock: true} };
    let b = this.convertObject(a);
    b._obj; // This is returning typeof a string

Comment: (It works, but the typing on the IDE will think it is a string)

Comment: Property 'value4' does not exist on type 'string'.

Comment: Updated my answer. This will probably be what you want but I don't think the IDE is smart enough to give you good intellisense on this:

Comment: actually, the typescript compiler is going to complain about this one, even though it's technically the correct typings. I don't know if TypeScript is powerful enough here to accomplish what you want